# How to make a function that would give one output 20% of the time, another output 10% of the time, and another output 70% of the time?

Tags: python

I attempted

```
import random
from statistics import mode

numlist = []
for i in range(6):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 4))
for i in range(3):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 3))
for i in range(1):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 2))

print(mode(numlist))
```

Which I attempted to give 1 number 70% of the time, another number 20% of the time, and another number 10% of the time. 
However, working out the math, the split ends of being 50%, 30%, 20%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reinventing the choise with probabilities field p

```
x = np.random.choice([2,3,4], 1, p=[0.2, 0.1, 0.7])
random.randint(1, x)
```

Comment: No need to involve numpy in this. `lambda: random.choices([2, 3, 4], [0.2, 0.1, 0.7])`

Comment: contrary to the docs of numpy, `random.choices` accepts an array of weights, of which the probabilities are the (approximate) normalization to a unit sum. So `random.choices([2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 7])` would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

When you use range(6) it returns 0,1,2,3,4,5.  Your code returns a  60-30-10 list.

```
import random
from statistics import mode

numlist = []
for i in range(7):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 4))
for i in range(2):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 3))
for i in range(1):
    numlist.append(random.randint(1, 2))
```

Here it is wrapped in an function that lets you determine how many decades to include in your output.

```
import random

# stt for seven-twenty-ten
def stt_split(n=1):
    # returns lists with lengths that are multiples of ten
    numlist = []
    for decades in range(n):
        for i in range(7):
            numlist.append(random.randint(1, 4))
        for i in range(2):
            numlist.append(random.randint(1, 3))
        for i in range(1):
            numlist.append(random.randint(1, 2))
    return numlist

alice = stt_split()
print(alice) # 10 values in a list

bob = stt_split(4)
print(bob) # 40 values in a list
```

On the other hand, if you don't want a list with a set distribution returned, but you want the function to return a value calculated by a randomly selected function, you could try something like this.

```
import random

# stt for seven-twenty-ten
def stt_dice(n=1):
    # returns lists of random ints with length n
    numlist = []
    for decades in range(n):
        x = random.choices([2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 7])[0]    
        numlist.append(random.randint(1, x))
    return numlist

alice = stt_dice()
print(alice) # 1 value in a list

bob = stt_dice(10)
print(bob) # 10 values in a list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = random.random(0, 9)
if i <= 1:
    <10% of the time>
elif i <= 3:
    <20% of the time>
else:
    <70% of the time>
```

Comment: Almost. Your comment is just off. (I mean the parts in <...>)

Comment: I think you need `<` instead of `<=` to get the correct percentage.

Comment: For randint(0, 9) you'd need <; for random(0, 9) you'd need <=. Modified the answer to use random(0, 9).

Comment: Actually, `random.random(0, 9)` raises a `TypeError: random() takes no arguments (2 given)`. Maybe you mean `random.uniform(0, 9)`.

Comment: Good catch, that's correct